# Centering the webpage content

Tags: css, html, centering

I need an advice about how to center article2 element. Here is the HTML code:

```
<article class="article2">

    <h1 class = "nadpis2">Co nabízím?</h1>
    <h2 class = "nadpis3">Jaké služby vám mohu nabídnout a jak se domluvit?</h2>  


      <div class="img">
        <img src="obr-kontakt.png" alt="">
        <div class="desc">Zkontaktujte mne</div>
      </div>

      <div class="img">
        <img src="obr-wait.png" alt="">
        <div class="desc">Vyčkejte na odpověď</div>
      </div>

      <div class="img">
        <img src="obr-lidi.png" alt="">
        <div class="desc">Domluvíme se na vašich požadavcích</div>
      </div>

      <div class="img">
        <img src="obr-design.png" alt="">
        <div class="desc">Vytvořím vám design na míru</div>
      </div>

      <div class="img">
        <img src="obr-html.png" alt="">
        <div class="desc">Pomocí HTML/CSS web zrealizuji</div>
      </div>

      <div class="img">
        <img src="obr-penize.png" alt="">
        <div class="desc">Web vám prodám za nejnižší ceny</div>
      </div>

</article>
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
.article2 {
 padding-top: 20px;
 height: 900px;
 width: auto;
 background-color: white;
 margin: auto;
 }


  .img{
  padding: 7px 90px 90px 90px;
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  float:left;
  text-align:center; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

.img img
  {
  display:inline;
  margin:5px;

  }

.desc
  {
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'Abel';
  font-size: 20px;
  width:120px;
  margin:5px;
  }
```

Also, when I change the browser window size, It pretty much destroys the whole page concept because It expands a lot.

**EDIT:** I actually need those images to be centered on the page. They are containered in the article element.

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You're missing the closing `</article>` is this how it is in your code or was this a copy paste error? Can you include a fiddle in your post?

Comment: You have `class="article2`, but it's `.article1` in the CSS, for what that's worth.  If you're not wanting it to expand, you'll have to set a fixed width.

Comment: Sorry, I accidently added wrong part of CSS. It is edited now even with the article element closed. Thanks

Comment: To what do you need your article element centered, is it to a container element?

Comment: I actually need those images to be centered on the page. They are containered in the article element.

Comment: If you want the images to be centered you will need to remove float:left and add specific width and display:block. Another solution would be to make the article element position: relative and position the .img elements with something like position:absolute left: 50%; (-webkit/-ms/-moz)-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the light of you last comment, I'll go for a table (See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/LyL93/1/)

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="obr-kontakt.png" alt=""/>
                <div class="desc">Zkontaktujte mne</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="obr-wait.png" alt=""/>
                <div class="desc">Vyčkejte na odpověď</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="obr-lidi.png" alt=""/>
                <div class="desc">Domluvíme se na vašich požadavcích</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="obr-design.png" alt=""/>
                <div class="desc">Vytvořím vám design na míru</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="obr-html.png" alt=""/>
                <div class="desc">Pomocí HTML/CSS web zrealizuji</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <img src="obr-penize.png" alt=""/>
               <div class="desc">Web vám prodám za nejnižší ceny</div>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And a simplified CSS, as follows:

```
.article1 {
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 850px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid 1px red;
} 

table {
    margin: auto;
}
td {
    padding:5px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.desc {
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'Abel';
  font-size: 20px;
  width:120px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It is working! Just last thing: when I change the size of the browser window, the table does not change the size with it. The article changes but not the table..Do you know, how to fix that?

Comment: You might want to add width: 100% to the table tag. I have updated the fiddle accordingly (and made some changes to visualize DOM elements with color). http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/LyL93/2/

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a width to .article1.

See my fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/LyL93/

```
.article1 {
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 850px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

I also fixed several typo or inconstancies : .article1, closing tags, etc.

Comment: The thing is, that i need to position the pictures like this: http://www.gliffy.com/go/publish/image/5764690/L.png - Sorry about those two squares on the left.

Comment: I would got for a simple table then. Is this something you would try? (I can do a fiddle for you if required)

Answer (score 0):

thats some css I usualy use... Try it yourself

```
html {
    height:100%; 
    max-height:100%; 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
    border:0; 
    overflow:hidden; 
}

body {
    position:relative;
    height:100%; 
    max-height:100%; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
    border:0; 
}

.article2 {
 padding-top: 20px;
 height: 900px;
 /*width: auto;*/
 width:1000px; /* you probably need a width so margin:auto will work  */
 margin: auto;
}
```